how to prevent this list from being updated?
my program:
num_cards=8
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
shuffle_cards=list1
for j in range(0,num_cards//2):
    shuffle_cards.insert((2*j)+1,shuffle_cards[(num_cards//2)+(2*j)])
shuffle_cards=shuffle_cards[0:num_cards]
print(shuffle_cards)
print(list1)

I havent updated list1, but it is also getting updated
output
I want only shuffle_cards to get updated when i insert element and not list1

You are confusing variables names and the objects they point to. If shuffle_cards=list1 you have 2 variables pointing to the same object. You don't update the variable list1 but you do update the object it points to. If you want a different object, you need to copy it: shuffle_cards=list1.copy()

This question is similar to: Changing one list unexpectedly changes another, too. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And see also List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly, Does Python make a copy of objects on assignment? and What is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?

Try creating a copy of list1 one using shuffle_cards = list1.copy() before the for loop.
num_cards = 8
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
shuffle_cards = list1.copy() 
for j in range(0, num_cards // 2):
    shuffle_cards.insert((2 * j) + 1, shuffle_cards[(num_cards // 2) + (2 * j)])
shuffle_cards = shuffle_cards[0:num_cards]
print(shuffle_cards)
print(list1)

Explanation:
Instead of shuffling the original list1, you first create a copy of it that you will shuffle shuffle_cards
after the for loop, you will have shuffled cards with print(shuffle_cards) and your original list1 with print(list1)

You would need to copy make a copy of the list.
When you wrote:
shuffle_cards=list1

You made it so that it points back to the original list.
